# Find largest intersection of groups within groups from multiple multi-class classifications

Tags: r, dplyr, intersection, multiclass-classification

I have different algorithms that classify individuals into groups A,B,C, or D.

The predicted classification data set looks like (it is a mess!) :

```
# sample data
df_orig = tibble(
  Individuals = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7),
  Algorithm_1 = c("A", "B", "A", "C", "A", "A", "D"),
  Algorithm_2 = c("B", "C", "B", "D", "C", "A", "D"),
  Algorithm_3 = c("C", "D", "D", "B", "D", "B", "A"),
  Algorithm_4 = c("D", "B", "C", "A", "B", "A", "A")
)
```

The groups have only fuzzy overlaps.
I now want to know which classes have the largest overlap/intersection in individuals across algorithms.

The desired output could be something like (only made-up example values)

|  | Algorithm_1 | Algorithm_2 | Algorithm_3 | Algorithm_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BestFit1 | class_A | class_B | class_D | class_C |
| BestFit2 | class_C | class_A | class_B | class_D |
| BestFit3 | class_B | class_B | class_D | class_A |
| BestFit3 | class_D | class_C | class_D | class_B |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

So far I have tried around with set theoretical approaches `Reduce(intersect())` but the Reduce does not seem work well on nested `dplyr::` structures (or I use it wrong)

```
df_test <- df_orig %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  rename(individual = rowname) %>% 
  mutate(individual = individual %>% as.numeric) %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("A"), names_to="algorithm", values_to = "prediction") %>% 
  pivot_wider(values_from = individual, names_from = individual, names_prefix = "I_") %>% 
  nest(individuals  = starts_with("I")) %>% mutate(individuals = lapply(`individuals`, function(x) x[!is.na(x)]))

Reduce(dplyr::intersect, df_test$individuals)
```

only gives `numeric(0)`; to `split` the nested structure does not account for the conditional overlaps based on both algorithm and class prediction.

I have also considered a correlational approach, such as

```
# compute correlation
prediction_matrix <- model.matrix(~0+., data=df_orig %>% select(-individuals)) %>% 
  cor(use="pairwise.complete.obs")
```

However, this rather gives me best pairwise correlations, not the best multi-set across multiple classes.

I am a bit a loss, hope someone smarter can help?

Comment: could you potentially show us what the *actual* desired output would be on the *actual* sample dataframe df_orig? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you are looking for some term frequency, inverse document frequency transform? Or a measure of statistical agreement? What is the ultimate aim?

Comment: The goal is to see which classes from each algorithm match which other classes from other algorithms based on a common set of individuals i. Say we have 5 i, 3 of which are predicted to be in A1_classA; 2 of those appear in cluster A2_classB (making the overlap between A1_classA and A2_classB a set of 2); the overlap between A1_classA and  A3_classB could be 3, between A2_classB and A3_classB 2 individuals, and A4_classC with A1_classA: 2, with A2_classB: 1, A3_classB: 3. If there is not better overlap with other algorithms, I want to match A1_classA, A2_classB, A3_classB, and A4_classC...

Comment: also, I did look into graphs, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47372430/r-find-groups-of-vectors-that-have-a-80-overlap-in-their-elements and and pairwise matches https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64736772/find-length-of-intersect-between-all-pairs-of-variables?rq=3, just that this problem is somwhat nested at a higher order, too.

Answer (score 1):

starting from your example data `df_orig`, you can:

- define a helper function which, for every item of a vector counts its equals among the remaining items:

```
count_matches <- function(xs) unlist(Map(seq_along(xs), f = \(i) sum(xs[i] == xs[-i])))

## > count_matches(c('A', 'B', 'A'))
## [1] 1 0 1
```

- line up a couple of dataframe manipulations from the *tidyverse* like so:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

df_orig |>
  pivot_longer(-Individuals, names_to = 'Algorithm', values_to = 'Class') |>
  mutate(cnt = count_matches(Class), .by = Individuals) |>
  summarise(cnt = sum(cnt), .by = c(Algorithm, Class)) |>
  arrange(Algorithm, desc(cnt)) |>
  mutate(Rank = row_number(), 
         Algorithm = gsub('lgorithm', '', Algorithm), ## shorten column labels
         .by = Algorithm
  ) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = Algorithm, values_from = c(Class, cnt), 
              names_vary = 'slowest'
              )
```

output:

```
## + # A tibble: 4 x 9
##    Rank Class_A_1 cnt_A_1 Class_A_2 cnt_A_2 Class_A_3 cnt_A_3 Class_A_4 cnt_A_4
##   <int> <chr>       <int> <chr>       <int> <chr>       <int> <chr>       <int>
## 1     1 A               2 A               2 A               1 A               3
## 2     2 B               1 D               1 C               0 B               1
## 3     3 D               1 B               0 D               0 D               0
## 4     4 C               0 C               0 B               0 C               0
```

A(lgorithm) 1 shows the highest consent (with other algos) for Class A, sharing his classification with others in 2 instances (across individuals and algos) etc.

Comment: Thanks! Almost. Here you get the matching predictions of the same class by individual, right? I guess I should have clarified a bit more (just that I am struggling to even formulate the problem right). The problem is that class A from Algorithm 1 is not necessarily equal to class A from algorithm 2. Say, we look at three individuals x,y,z. If algorithm 1 predicts x and z to be part of cluster A, but algorithm 2 predicts x,y,and z to be part of cluster B, I would like to match Alg1_classA with Alg2_class B. Does that make it clearer? Happy to modify the question, once I can formulate it better.

Comment: I'll have a look at it later. Sounds clear though.